# Derivative check with scalers

Tags: derivative, openmdao

I have a problem that I want to scale the design variables. I have added the scaler, but I want to check the derivative to make sure it is doing what I want it to do. Is there a way to check the scaled derivative? I have tried to use check_total_derivatives() but the derivative is the exact same regardless of what value I put for scaler:

```
from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem, IndepVarComp, ExecComp
from openmdao.drivers.pyoptsparse_driver import pyOptSparseDriver

class Scaling(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scaling, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('x', shape=1)
        self.add_output('y', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['y'] = 1000. * params['x']**2 + 2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}
        J['y', 'x'] = 2000. * params['x']
        return J


class ScalingGroup(Group):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(ScalingGroup, self).__init__()
        self.add('x', IndepVarComp('x', 0.0), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('g', Scaling(), promotes=['*'])

p = Problem()
p.root = ScalingGroup()

# p.driver = pyOptSparseDriver()
# p.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SNOPT'
p.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.005, upper=100., scaler=1000)
p.driver.add_objective('y')
p.setup()
p['x'] = 3.

p.run()
total = p.check_total_derivatives()
# Derivative is the same regardless of what the scaler is.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to see exactly what the optimizer is seeing from calc_gradient is to mimic the call to calc_gradient. This is not necessarily easy to figure out, but I thought I would paste it here for reference.

```
print p.calc_gradient(list(p.driver.get_desvars().keys()),
                      list(p.driver.get_objectives().keys()) + list(p.driver.get_constraints().keys()),
                      dv_scale=p.driver.dv_conversions,
                      cn_scale=p.driver.fn_conversions)
```

Answer (score 3):

The scalers and adders are consistent in their behavior, so the check derivatives routines give results in unscaled terms to be more intuitive.

If you really want to see what impact the scaler is having when the NLP sees the scaled value and you're using SNOPT, you can add SNOPT's derivative check capability:

`p.driver.opt_settings['Verify level'] = 3`

SNOPT_print.out will contain, with the scaler set to 1:

 `Column       x(j)        dx(j)    Element no.    Row        Derivative    Difference approxn
      1  3.00000000E+00  2.19E-06           Objective    6.00000000E+03   6.00000219E+03  ok`

Or if we change it to the x scaler to 1000:

```
Column       x(j)        dx(j)    Element no.    Row        Derivative    Difference approxn
      1  3.00000000E+03  1.64E-03           Objective    6.00000000E+00    6.00000164E+00  ok
```

So in the units of the problem, which check_total_derivatives uses, the derivative doesn't change.  But the scaled value as seen by the optimizer is changing.